# How can I better test an actionCreator that uses electrons

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron, jestjs

Here is a sample actioncreator. It dispacthes the correct action and then tries to persist the data that has been updated in the store to the file system (this is an electron app).

Everything works, but I have a question about testing the action creator.

```
...

function persistClasses(dispatch: Function, getState: Function, callback: Function) {
  writeAppData(
    {
      [FILE_CLASSES]: JSON.stringify({[CLASSES]: getState()[CLASSES]})
    },
    (ioResult: Object) => {
      if (ioResult.success) {
        dispatch(persitingDataSuccess(CLASSES));
      } else {
        dispatch(persitingDataError(CLASSES));
      }

      callback(ioResult);
    }
  );
}

export function replaceClasses(updatedData: Array<Object>, callback: Function): ActionObj {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: REPLACE_CLASSES,
      payload: updatedData,
    });

    persistClasses(dispatch, getState, callback);
  };
}

...


function writeAppData(content: Object, callback: Function) {
  let files = DATA_PATHS.filter(filePath => content[filePath] !== undefined)
    .map(filePath => {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const FILE_PATH = getFilePath(filePath);

      fs.writeFile(FILE_PATH, content[filePath], 'UTF-8', (err?: any) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(FILE_PATH);
        }
      });
  });
});

  Promise.all(files)
.then(
  responses => {
    callback({
      success: true,
      errorObj: null,
    });
  }
)
.catch(
  err => {
    callback({
      success: false,
      errorObj: err,
    });
  }
);
}

...
```

The following test works but it only tests what happens in my replaceClasses action.

How can I test what persistClasses does?

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as classActions from '../classActions';
import { REPLACE_CLASSES, UPDATE_CLASS, ADD_CLASS, DELETE_ALL_CLASSES } from '../../constants/actionTypes';
import ClassDefault from '../../types/class';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);


/**
* Class Actions Tests
*/

describe('Actions: classActions:', () => {
  let testClass = {};
  let callback = function(){};
  let store = function(){};

  beforeEach(() => {
    testClass = {...ClassDefault, id: 'c1', label: 'Class'};
    callback = jest.fn();
    store = mockStore({ classes: [] });
  });

  test('replaceClasses dispatches the correct action', () => {
    const EXPECTED_ACTIONS = [
      { type: REPLACE_CLASSES, payload: [testClass] },
    ];

    store.dispatch(classActions.replaceClasses([testClass], callback));
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(EXPECTED_ACTIONS);
  });

  ...

 });
```

I'm not sure if I need to test it as it just uses electron's I/O methods which I think would be covered by electron's own tests. Or is there away I can test it? I don't think as it is the test environment that there is access to electron.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that come to my mind:

**By composition**

Make the `replaceClasses` function accept a function argument called i.e. `writeDataFn`. Then in your test you can just pass a spy and check if it was invoked with proper arguments.

**Using `proxyquire`**

https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire

Thanks to this module you can `import` a module mocking some of its dependencies. For example:

```
const classActions = proxyquire('../classActions, { writeAppData: () => 'I'm a spy!' });
```

---

By the way - I strongly recommend to use TDD approach in development - you'll not have issues like this one :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development